# Compare NULL Parameters with columns that may contain NULL values

Tags: sql-server, parameters, server, null, isnull

I'm trying to work on SQL Server with some parameters that can be NULL, where NULL means "ignore this parameter".

Then I have the column where the middle name is stored and can contain nulls.

I have the following conditions that works really fast:

```
T.tr_ben_name           =   ISNULL(@BenFirstName,       T.tr_send_name)     AND
T.tr_ben_middle         =   ISNULL(@BenMiddleName,      T.tr_send_middle)   AND
T.tr_ben_last           =   ISNULL(@BenLastName,        T.tr_send_last)     AND
T.tr_ben_last2          =   ISNULL(@BenSecondLastName,  T.tr_send_last2 )
```

But for some reason if the middle name value and the corresponding parameter are both NULL the record will be skipped, even if I turn off ANSI NULLS.

Then I came up with this other version that works well but 4 times slower:

```
(T.tr_ben_name          =   @BenFirstName       OR  @BenFirstName       IS NULL)    AND
(T.tr_ben_middle        =   @BenMiddleName      OR  @BenMiddleName      IS NULL)    AND
(T.tr_ben_last          =   @BenLastName        OR  @BenLastName        IS NULL)    AND
(T.tr_ben_last2         =   @BenSecondLastName  OR  @BenSecondLastName  IS NULL)
```

Can anyone explain what is the difference between these 2 approaches?

Comment: What if you use `IIF()` instead of `ISNULL()`

Comment: The first one isn't working because you are using a different column when the parameter is null. Your two queries do NOT do the same thing. However, this is a type of catch-all query. Gail Shaw has a great article about that [here](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) and a follow up [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlinthewild/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/)

Comment: @SeanLange but the first version still wouldn't work if both the column and the parameter are `NULL`, while the second query would

Comment: OR clause is slower in SQL‌ queries and you used that.

Comment: If `NULL` is supplied for `@BenFirstName`, what value should `T.tr_ben_name` have, `NULL` or any given value? If the former, the syntax would actually be `AND (T.tr_ben_name = @BenFirstName OR (T.tr_ben_name IS NULL AND @BenFirstName IS NULL))`, if the latter, your second query is correct. Either way, this'll suffer from the problems @SeanLange mentioned.

Comment: @Lamak right, but they are replacing the parameter with a different column, the second query is using the original column.

Comment: `T.tr_ben_middle = ISNULL(@BenMiddleName, T.tr_send_middle)` will essentially become `NULL = NULL` which is `FALSE` since `NULL` can't be equal to anything, even itself. And since you use `AND`, you've now made your entire condition fail.

Comment: @SeanLange ah, yes, I understood. I'm just saying that if OP used the same column, it still wouldn't work as they want

Comment: @Lamak indeed.. :)

Comment: Also, is `NULL` passed in the `@`variables, or is it coming over as an empty string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a short summary of why the queries perform differently, and what you can do to help the performance. For more details, see [Catch-All Queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) and [Revisiting Catch-all Queries](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlinthewild/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/) by Gail Shaw. For an exhaustive analysis, see [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) By Erland Sommarskog.

Basically, the query with conditional parameters tries to create a query plan that works for all possible combinations of parameters passed in. This means that it doesn't default to lookup by index seek if you pass in the seekable parameters only. Instead, it uses some query plan that is usable for any combination of parameters.

Basic fixes for this issue are

1. Add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` on the end of your query (SQL 2008 R2 SP1, 2008 SP3, or higher only)
2. Use Dynamic SQL. Only add the conditions being checked with non-null parameters.

If you want the full detailed whys and wherefores, the articles above are very good.

Comment: NOTE: The Sommarskog article does a full analysis on the various types of joins (as in the suggestions above) and shows that they all reduce to one of two basic but inefficient query plan forms.